# iTextSharp Overlay two pdf files

Tags: c#, .net, pdf, itext

I have 2 pdf documents. One with the actual content pdf, the second one is a letterhead pdf. I'm trying to overlay one on the other one but the issue is once overlapped content is over letterhead as well. Here is the code that I have recently. My question is how can I put the content between header and footer? Thanks in advance.

```cs
string originalPdfPath = @"C:\Users\BiberEmr\Downloads\testPdf\ThreePageContent.pdf";
string letterHeadPath = @"C:\Users\BiberEmr\Downloads\testPdf\letterhead_lorenzo.pdf";
   
// Opening reader on content PDF and creating stamper
PdfReader contentReader = new PdfReader(originalPdfPath);
PdfStamper stamper = new PdfStamper(contentReader, new FileStream(@"C:\Users\BiberEmr\Downloads\testPdf\result2.pdf", FileMode.Create));

// Opening template pdf
PdfReader templateReader = new PdfReader(letterHeadPath);
PdfImportedPage templatePage = stamper.GetImportedPage(templateReader, 1);

// Looping through pages
for (int i = 1; i <= contentReader.NumberOfPages; i++)
{
    // Retrieve content page where to apply template
    PdfContentByte contentPage = stamper.GetUnderContent(i);

    // Apply template to PDF content
    contentPage.AddTemplate(templatePage, 0, 50);
}

stamper.Close();
templateReader.Close();
contentReader.Close();
```

Here is the current output

| Page 1 | Page2 |
| --- | --- |
| [image: page1] | [image: page2] |

Comment: The best option would be to take the areas later used by header and footer into account already when creating the content PDFs, e.g. by assigning large enough margins.

Comment: Can you please tell me how to do that in the code snippet above maybe? I'm not really familiar with itextsharp itself?

Comment: In the code above it's too late for that best option - that code simply takes *existing* pdfs and overlays them. What i meant is that one should already consider header and footer space when *creating* the pdf with the content.

Comment: If you want to stay in the iText ecosystem and manage these sort of compositions regularly, I'd recommend iText DITO that allows you to create standard, header and footer templates, and compositions, which are combinations of the other three types of template: https://itextpdf.com/en/resources/media/files/itext-dito-20-release-preview-guide